# I have the following contract deployed but i get an error anytime i call TransferRewards

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Contract address is

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x6eef14237fdc122a70651b11560cffb2fe57ca1a#writeContract

whatever i do i get an error at transfer rewards and it's driving me crazy

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the `sendRewards()` function (as there's no `TransferRewards()`). From which address are you trying to execute it, and what value are you passing to the `_amount` param?

Comment: @PetrHejda there is a separate staking contract which has to interact with this Treasury contract it is based on the OlympusDAO contracts,but when they execute the sendrewards function they  get "Error: Returned error: execution reverted: SafeMath: subtraction overflow"

Comment: The "substraction overflow" comes from the `SafeMath` `sub()` function, however it's not called from the `sendRewards()` function, so it's probably an unrelated issue to the original question. Please edit the question or post a comment with steps to reproduce the issue that you're getting.